# Is there a way to calculate how much income tax I will pay in France?

Tags: taxes, france, online-resources

I'm currently working in France as an Expat. Having received my last pay-check for 2015, I would like to calculate how much income tax I will have to pay for the 2015 fiscal year. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is a terrible question but I'll upvote it in return for a bribe.

Comment: Relevant article with relevant links inside for caluclating the tax: http://www.thelocal.fr/20160413/france-tax-declaration-season-opens-heres-how-it-all-works

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I'm going to need that this year too. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this online. [The French government has an Impots website, which allows you to calculate your income tax, based on the information you have (in French).](http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup?typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_705) You can compute the taxes for the current fiscal year and for the three previous years by clicking on ["*Accéder au simulateur*"](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/simulateurs). It is worthy to note that the website calls this a simulation rather than a calculation since the real amount you'll have to pay will be the one marked on the official document you'll receive after filing in your declaration.

There are two types of income tax declaration forms: [simplified and complete](http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup;jsessionid=FYAYTHCQA04HZQFIEIPSFFA?espId=&typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_335). The one you use depends on the sources of your income (quoting from the linked website in French):

> #### Le modèle simplifié (déclaration n° 2042)
>
> Vous pouvez utiliser le modèle simplifié, si vos revenus comprennent seulement :
>
> - des salaires
> - des pensions ou retraites
> - des revenus de valeurs et capitaux mobiliers
> - des revenus fonciers
> - des plus-values et gains divers
>
> Ou si, par exemple , vous déclarez les charges suivantes :
>
> - pensions alimentaires
> - dons aux oeuvres
> - enfants à charge poursuivant des études (collège, lycée, enseignement supérieur)
> - frais de garde d'enfants
> - emploi d'un salarié à domicile
> - ...
>
> #### Le modèle complet
>
> Si certains de vos revenus ou charges n'entrent pas tous dans la déclaration "de base" (2042), vous devez utiliser le modèle complet.
>   C'est le cas si vous avez :
>
> - des revenus d'activité autre que salariée (commerciale, libérale, agricole,...)
> - des investissements locatifs
> - des déficits globaux (déficits professionnels,...)
>
> Le modèle complet reprend la déclaration "de base" à laquelle s'ajoutent les déclarations complémentaires.

[Here is the google-translate English version of this same web page.](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.impots.gouv.fr%2Fportal%2Fdgi%2Fpublic%2Fpopup%3Bjsessionid%3DFYAYTHCQA04HZQFIEIPSFFA%3FespId%3D%26typePage%3Dcpr02%26docOid%3Ddocumentstandard_335&edit-text=&act=url)

Various other websites provide similar simulators, however I would stick with the governmental one for a matter of accuracy.